# Django count grouping by year/month without extra

Tags: python, django, aggregate, annotate

I'm working with django 1.9

Model :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As 'extra()' will be deprecated in django i try to figure out how to count Comments group by year-month without using 'extra'

Here is the code with extra :

```
Comment.objects.extra(select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM date)",
    'month': "EXTRACT(month from date)"})\
    .values('year', 'month').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are using `extra` to the question?

Comment: Good idea, i've added it in the question.
Thank you.

Comment: Using [RawSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL) might be a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [year and month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#year) in the docs, may be something like the following will do the job:

```
Comment.objects.annotate(year=Q(date__year), 
                         month=Q(date__month)
                         ).values('year', 'month').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

If this won't work, then instead of Q(date__year), you could define a custom [Func()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression representing `EXTRACT(year FROM date)` function and use it in `annotate()`. Or, well, as last resort there's [RawSQL()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions).

Using `Func()`, something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Extract(Func):
    """
    Performs extraction of `what_to_extract` from `*expressions`.

    Arguments:
        *expressions (string): Only single value is supported, should be field name to
                               extract from.
        what_to_extract (string): Extraction specificator.

    Returns:
        class: Func() expression class, representing 'EXTRACT(`what_to_extract` FROM `*expressions`)'.
    """

    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(what_to_extract)s FROM %(expressions)s)'


#Usage
Comment.objects.annotate(year=Extract(date, what_to_extract='year'), 
                             month=Extract(date, what_to_extract='month')
                             ).values('year', 'month').annotate(Count('pk'))
```

Comment: Yes i've read the year month doc, and i've understood that date__year is a field lookup reserved to the `filter`, `get` and `exclude` methods. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups). 

I can't get a valid code with your `Func()` proposal. I'm digging it today.

I could solve this with rawSQL, but i thought the deprecation of `extra()` was due to a better api we could use to deal with all `extra()` situations.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the docs, but have you tried them wrapped in Q-objects. Just hoped it would work out somehow this way. =) Basicly with `Func()` you can wrap RawSQL function in reusable function to use in Django ORM methods.

Comment: @Ange Concerto, see answer update, added a snippet for `Func()` in answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you're using Sqlite as a database, as that doesn't support `EXTRACT()`.

Comment: @PhilGyford SQLite has a lot of limitations overall, so in production you probably want something more powerful. Secondly, this whole question is not relevant to SQLite as the `EXTRACT()` statement is in the question itself and SQLite doesn't support `datetime` type, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @PhilGyford For SQLite you will have to store `datetime` as a timestamp in `REAL` type and process it in the app, or store separate `INTEGER` fields for each part of a date and process them in the app.

Comment: @Nikita I'm not criticising, just pointing out to anyone else who comes here wondering why it's not working with their SQLite :) It's common to use SQLite in development or experimenting. And when writing an app I expect other people to use, I try to make sure it works as widely as possible, which is why I was testing with SQLite.